# How can I use the Jquery fadein/fadeout without reloading the page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to create a website with an audio player that plays as users traverse through the site. At the same time, the content section needs to fade out and back in while this is still going on. So bring in another piece of HTML without reloading the page. The question I have is, how can i get all those to run correctly, while at the same time, running different Jquery plugins on different pages?

Essentially, I need to website to run like this one but with a continuous audio player in the corner or something.
http://www.chalicerecording.com/

If you notice, the page never reloads and the name of the actual file doesnt display on the browser top. This gives me the idea thats its using PHP for the page.

So with that idea, I ended up finding this.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytKc0QsVRY4

The problem im having with that is that I cant seem to figure out a way to run individual Jquery plugins on each individual PHP page without reloading the entire page. I hope this is enough info for you guys to work with.

Comment: Yes I have. Whats going on is when the paage initially loads, any jquery plugins that are on that initial page load and run. But when you click on any link within the navigation, the page changes, but the JavaScript doesnt reload and display the new plugins. Would AJAX fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use ajax calls to do so

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

[jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

you also need to use jQuery [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) , jQuery [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: Alright. Can you point me in the right direction to learn this stuff?

Comment: little example http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/ajax
and if this was the answer of your question please mark it

Comment: That is correct for the most part yes. But would that run any jquery plugins that are within those individual pages that are loaded? Like I said, the problem Im having is that the plugins will not load.

Comment: these functions I mentioned above are part of jQuery API so will work for sure if you included the jQuery plugin
here is another example that explains your point
http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

Comment: That is actually exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.